# Performance issues when deleting a record with Cosmo DB in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem deleting a record. I am doing a CRUD and I can already list the data and create new ones but when I want to delete some I get this error. I changed the default renderer and I'm using the NewtonsoftJson so Program.cs looks like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

My model is the following:

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Reflection;

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]

        public string id { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userNameChannel")]
        public string userNameChannel { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "channel")]
        public string channel { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "registerDate")]
        public DateTime registerDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phone")]
        public string phone { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fullName")]
        public string fullName { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        public string email { get; set; } = "";

    }
}
```

And in my controller as methods to delete I am using this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    try
    {
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);
        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = @id")
            .WithParameter("@id", id);

        var result = await container.GetItemQueryIterator<UserModel>(query).ReadNextAsync();
        var user = result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
    }
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    try
    {
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);

        var result = await container.DeleteItemStreamAsync(id, new PartitionKey(id));

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");                }


    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
    }
}
```

And as I mentioned at the beginning, the error I have is the following:

[image]

It's very frustrating not being able to delete a record. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try setting [ReferenceLoopHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ReferenceLoopHandling)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `ToString()` representation of your exception as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: You can improve the efficiency of getting a single user document by performing a point read using the following: `container.ReadItemAsync<UserModel>(id, partitionKey)`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. The title mentions "performance issues" but the body of the question is about some serialization error. What are you actually asking? How to avoid the serialization error? You need to provide the full stack trace in text format as it isn't obvious to me what line of your code is reproducing that error.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing has nothing to do with performance and it is not related to deleting the Cosmos item.

The error is coming from the ASP.NET renderer from your GET operation:

```
var user = result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
```

`user` is not of type `UserModel`.

First and foremost, if you are reading a single item, **do not execute a query**, Cosmos DB is not SQL Server. Do a point read:

```
ublic async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    try
    {
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_config["CosmosDB:DatabaseName"], _config["CosmosDB:ContainerName"]);
        var result = await container.ReadItemAsync<UserModel>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
        
        return View(result.Resource);
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, ex);
    }
}
```

And make sure you return the `result.Resource`.

Lastly, if you are performing any query on your application (not this case because you should replace it with ReadItem), you should be **draining always all pages**, do not assume that the result will be in the first page, always drain until the iterator `HasMoreResults` is false: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator-1?view=azure-dotnet#examples

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why your performance is poor.

1. You are getting a new container reference on each invocation. Get this reference once and maintain for the life of the application.
2. You are executing a query to look up an item which you then delete. There's no reason to do this.
3. I can't think of a reason to use the stream version for DeleteItemAsync(). You basically lose the ability to catch errors using Cosmos Exception in a catch block.
4. Not related to performance but there is no reason to use JSON property decorators in your model if the property names are the same as what's in your documents.

Rewrite this a single controller action "Delete" with id as string, then call DeleteItemAsync() from a hydrated container reference in a try block and performance should be good.
I'm a bit confused on why your controller is implemented this way with two separate Delete functions.

Comment: I was confused as well but I think the `Delete` action is showing a "user info" type of page which probably contains a delete or confirm delete button